# QGIS: it is possible to add labels to a polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling

My QGIS version is 3.22.5

I have a multiline string shapefile.

If I give a different attribute to each polygon of the shape (e.g. increasing ordinal numbers), is it possible to show these numbers as labels beside each polygon?

Comment: Yes : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html?highlight=label#ls-labels

Comment: do you have multilines or polygons?

Comment: In this case I have multilines but I think that labelling according to attributes could be useful also with polygons